# Upload file from local to SFTP via PHP SSH2

Tags: php, ssh, ftp, sftp

I am trying to upload a local file from my Mac to SFTP via PHP. My code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($server, $port);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $passwd)) {
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);
echo "Connection successful, uploading file now..."."\n";
$file = '/Users/petenaylor/Desktop/diamondexclusive.mp4';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}/{$file}", $contents);
} 
else {
    echo "Unable to authenticate with server"."n";
}
```

It connects as it should and I have checked that the local file location is correct, but the error messages I get are:

Warning: file_get_contents(/Users/petenaylor/Desktop/diamondexclusive.mp4): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/test.php on line 39

Warning: file_put_contents(): Unable to open ssh2.sftp://Resource id #3//Users/petenaylor/Desktop/diamondexclusive.mp4 on remote host in /home/test.php on line 40

Warning: file_put_contents(ssh2.sftp://Resource id #3//Users/petenaylor/Desktop/diamondexclusive.mp4): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/test.php on line 40

My log file from Filezilla:

```
Command:    put "/Users/petenaylor/Desktop/diamondexclusive.mp4" "diamondexclusive.mp4"
Status:         local:/Users/petenaylor/Desktop/diamondexclusive.mp4 => remote:/home/myfarewellnote/web/diamondexclusive.mp4
Trace:          FileTransferParseResponse(0)
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:          CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Status:         File transfer successful, transferred 12,661,295 bytes in 111 seconds
Status:         Retrieving directory listing of "/home/myfarewellnote/web"...
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ParseSubcommandResult(0)
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ListSubcommandResult()
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ListSend()
Command:    ls
Status:         Listing directory /home/myfarewellnote/web
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ListParseResponse()
Trace:          CSftpControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Trace:          CControlSocket::ResetOperation(0)
Status:         Directory listing of "/home/myfarewellnote/web" successful
```

Comment: Can you upload a file to the `/Users/petenaylor/Desktop/diamondexclusive.mp4` using a standalone (GUI or command line) SFTP client? If you can, show us its log file.

Comment: I can do it successfully via FileZilla. Shall I supply the log file from there?

Comment: Yes, please. Verbose log file.

Comment: It's large to fit in this window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FileZilla, you upload a file under a name `diamondexclusive.mp4` to the current remote working directory, which is `/home/myfarewellnote/web`.

Hence the full target path is `/home/myfarewellnote/web/diamondexclusive.mp4`.

While in PHP you upload the file to `/Users/petenaylor/Desktop/diamondexclusive.mp4` (what is actually a local source path, that has nothing to do with the server).

Use the same path that you upload the file to in FileZilla:

```
file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://{$sftp}/home/myfarewellnote/web/diamondexclusive.mp4", $contents);
```